# Can Spree allows me to create a site to rent places? similar to Airbnb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, location, customization, spree

I am tempted to use Spree to build a site where any user will be able to publish a place for rental, or rent a place, in a similar fashion to Airbnb.

People say spree is highly customisable, however most of examples and tutorials are based on a "store" where users only purchase from physical products.

I think that I can edit the Spree::User to grant more permissions so they can also publish. And I may be able to edit the products to include location. Products will be treated as unlimited stock so they are always there.

Then the products listing page will be very changed so that places appear based on user location / search location.

Will I be able to perform all of that or should I start looking other platform?

Comment: What about availability of the places? You should write custom code for dealing 'products' with some kind of calendar. Personally I wouldn't use Spree for this kind of app and any E-commerce platform. Once (RoR2) I've created a app for small hotel and that was not so hard.

Comment: @Jakub so you used Ruby on Rails to make it all on your own?

Comment: Yes I did. And I would do the same if I were you. Why you want to use Spree?

Comment: Well I thought that I could reuse all the included security processes, currency, checkouts, languages, etc. But if there are gems for every similar function to do a site like this probably i'll go with simple ROR as well.